# Sharepoint list export report not keeping column name order

Tags: sharepoint-2013

i have a report that relies to this sharepoint list. i just hit refresh then voila new data. However the SP site just changed and i have to connect it there, however
everytime i export an excel report from my sharepoint list it always gives me column names not in the correct order. i already double checked my connection 
i fixed the order in my list view and it saves correctly
how can i keep that same order when i export it to excel? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The order in the list view should be the order they exported as.  Try creating a new view (not based on any other view) and re-create your layout and then try to export again.